# How do I return all row values of a data value I put as an argument into a search function when using postgresql with python

Tags: python, postgresql

```
        import psycopg2
        
        def connect_table():
            connect= psycopg2.connect("dbname= 'bookshop' user='postgres' password='0973' host='localhost' port='5432'")
            cursor= connect.cursor()    
            cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books (ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, Title TEXT, Author TEXT, Year INTEGER, ISBN INTEGER UNIQUE)")
            connect.commit()     
            connect.close()
    
    def insert(Title,Author,Year,ISBN):
        connect= psycopg2.connect("dbname= 'bookshop' user='postgres' password='0973' host='localhost' port='5432'")
        cursor= connect.cursor() 
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO books (Title, Author, Year, ISBN) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (Title,Author,Year,ISBN))
        connect.commit()     
        connect.close()
    
    
    def view():
        connect= psycopg2.connect("dbname= 'bookshop' user='postgres' password='0973' host='localhost' port='5432'")
        cursor= connect.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * from books")
        rows= cursor.fetchall()      #Fetches all rows of a query result, returns it as a list of tuples
        connect.close()
        return rows
    
    def search(Title='',Author='',Year='',ISBN=''):
        connect= psycopg2.connect("dbname= 'bookshop' user='postgres' password='0973' host='localhost' port='5432'")
        cursor= connect.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * from books WHERE Title=%s OR Author=%s OR Year=%s OR ISBN=%s", (Title, Author, Year, ISBN))
        rows= cursor.fetchall()      #Fetches all rows of a query result, returns it as a list of tuples
        connect.close()
        return rows
    
print(search(Author= 'Tsu Chi'))
```

Above is my code and below is the error I am getting when I call the search function this way `print(search(Author= 'Tsu Chi'))`
. I want to be able to search for single data value and it will return the rows associated with it...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/daniel/Desktop/backend.py", line 77, in <module>
    print(search(Author= 'Tsu Chi'))
  File "c:/Users/daniel/Desktop/backend.py", line 36, in search
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from books WHERE Title=%s OR Author=%s OR Year=%s OR ISBN=%s", (Title, Author, Year, ISBN))
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: ""
LINE 1: ... books WHERE Title='' OR Author='Tsu Chi' OR Year='' OR ISBN...
```

Comment: Hi there! Could you please format your code a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like at least one of the fields (title, author, year or isbn) is of data type `int`. The default values that you defined for the function parameters caused psycopg2 to pass string values to all bind variables.

On a side note, it's usually better to keep one connection open and reuse it for all function calls.

Comment: so you suggest I reload my Table and then convert Year and ISBN to TEXT instead of string datatype ?

Comment: @danyyen no, I didn't say that you need to reload anything. What I'm saying is that bind variable types should correspond to the field data types. So "year" and "isbn" are integers, use integers in your Python program. When you assign them with an empty string default value then you force them to become strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint you gave me. I declared the Year,ISBN as integer variable...
---->   def search(Title='',Author='',Year=None,ISBN=None)
This worked perfectly without errors.
thanks once more

Answer (score 0):

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: ""
LINE 1: ... books WHERE Title='' OR Author='Tsu Chi' OR Year='' OR ISBN..
```

This error is because 'Year' and 'ISBN' are of type integer but you are passing empty strings to them.

If you want to make searches based on a single or multiple conditions try using variable-length keyword args like below code:

I am a noob coder so I don't know if this is the most elegant or efficient code but it should serve the purpose.

You can search with a single or multiple conditions in the 'where' clause and pass the required condition joiner(or/and) too.

```
def search(condition_joiner='',**kwargs):
    connect= psycopg2.connect("dbname= 'bookshop' user='postgres' password='0973' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cursor= connect.cursor()
    
    search_string='SELECT * from books WHERE '
    condition_count=0
    for key,value in kwargs.items():
        condition_count+=1
        if condition_count>1:
            search_string += condition_joiner
        search_key= ' {}={}'.format(key,value)
        search_string = search_string+search_key
    
    cursor.execute(search_string)
    rows= cursor.fetchall()      #Fetches all rows of a query result, returns it as a list of tuples
    connect.close()
    return rows
    

print(search(Author= '\'Tsu Chi\''))
```

Use the variable `search_string` to pass in the statement to `cursor.execute()`

`search_key` is where we put all the required conditions(1 or many) and attach it to `search_string` one by one.

If you have more than 1 condition `condition_joiner` is used to join the different conditions like `Author='some_author' OR Title='some_title'`

You can pass as many as required in `search()`. Make sure to use escape character \ to use quotes while passing strings.

Update if it works.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes this works but now it tampers with the insert function... I think I will convert the Year/ISBN column to a TEXT data type and try the search function again.. 
thanks

Comment: How does it tamper with the insert function?